# Complete factorization of $64y^6 - 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

If we use the difference of two cubes identity, then we have
$$64y^6 - 1 = (4y^2-1)(16y^4+4y^2+1) = (2y+1)(2y-1)(16y^4+4y^2+1)$$ which is the suggested solution of the textbook.

But if we use the difference of two squares identity, we then have
$$64y^6 - 1 = (8y^3+1)(8y^3-1) = (2y+1)(2y-1)(4y^2-2y+1)(4y^2+2y+1).$$

I then came up with the question: what is complete factorization? Of course we can do this trick:
$$16y^4+4y^2+1 = 16y^4+8y^2+1 - 4y^2 = (4y^2+1 - 2y)(4y^2+1+2y).$$
How do we know when to stop factorizing?

Comment: ok i have got this here $$\left( 2\,x-1 \right)  \left( 2\,x+1 \right)  \left( 4\,{x}^{2}+2\,x+
1 \right)  \left( 4\,{x}^{2}-2\,x+1 \right) 
$$

Comment: have you tried Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: The book is of course wrong.

Comment: In principle every real polynomial is a product of some list of real polynomials of first or second degree, so the factorization in the book is obviously "incomplete" in that sense. It's not always as easy to find the factorization in first and second degree polynomials as it is in this case, however.

Comment: it depends what field you factor over as that will determine your irreducible polynomials and it still won't give you a necessarily prime factorization for example 64x^6-1 is divisible by 3 any time x is not 0 mod 3 ( at least while x takes integer values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer   depends on the base ring/field you consider:

The complete factorisation over $\mathbf Z, \mathbf Q$ or $\mathbf R$ is indeed
$$(2x-1)(2x+1)(4x^2+2x+1)(4x^2-2x+1)$$

But on $\mathbf C$, you obtain a product of linear factors involving the sixth roots of unity:
\begin{align}
64x^6-1&=\prod_{k=1}^6\Bigl(2x-\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2ik\pi}{6}}\Bigr)\\
&=\underbrace{\Bigl(2x-\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi}{3}}\Bigr)\Bigl(2x-\mathrm e^{\tfrac{5i\pi}{3}}\Bigr)}_{\textstyle4x^2+2x+1}\,\underbrace{\Bigl(2x-\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2i\pi}{3}}\Bigr)\Bigl(2x-\mathrm e^{\tfrac{4i\pi}{3}}\Bigr)}_{\textstyle4x^2-2x+1}\,\Bigl(\underbrace{2x-\mathrm e^{\tfrac{3i\pi}{3}}\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{1.5ex}}_{\textstyle2x+1}\Bigr)\,\Bigl(\underbrace{2x-\mathrm e^{\tfrac{6i\pi}{3}}\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{1.5ex}}_{\textstyle2x-1}\Bigr)
\end{align}\,

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the factorization in $\mathbb{R}[x]$?
Note that for all real values $y$,
$$4y^2+1 - 2y=3y^2+(y-1)^2>0\quad 4y^2+1+2y=3y^2+(y+1)^2>0$$
so they cannot be factored as $a(y-y_1)(y-y_2)$ with $a,y_1,y_2\in \mathbb{R}$, otherwise they should be zero for $y_1$ and $y_2$.

Answer (score 1):

The polynomials $$p(y)=4y^2-2y+1$$ $$q(y)=4y^2+2y+1$$

have negative discriminants so they cannot be factorized over the field of real numbers.

$q(y),p(y)>0,\forall y$

Now if you want to include complex numbers then just solve the quadratics.

Then you will have a complete factorization over the complex field.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic problem in complex analysis.  Note first that $(1/2)^6 = 1/64$.  Then you need to look for the six roots of unity.  They are:
$$
e^{n \pi i },~~n=0, 1/3, ...,5/3
$$
So all six roots are
$$
(1/2)e^{n \pi i },~~n=0, 1/3, ...,5/3
$$ 
The n-th roots of unity form a group with the operation multiplication.  They're an important early example in abstract algebra.

Answer (score 1):

A simplistic answer for "when to stop factorizing" real polynomials is when every factor is either a first-degree real polynomial or an irreducible second-degree real polynomial.

A second-degree polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$ is irreducible when
$b^2 - 4ac < 0.$

I say this answer is "simplistic" because it ignores the problem of how you would actually obtain such a factorization from an arbitrary polynomial.